# Retrieving data from a list in fixed chunks

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I want to retrive data from a list in fixed sizes. Each chunk will form a table row and the elements in the chunk will form the table cells. The extracted chunks will be added to a list of lists that will form the whole table.
The list identified by variable row is :

```
[http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q151345, Billygoat Hennes, http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3569037, William Windsor, http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q23003932, His Whiskers]
```

The code am using is to retrieve the chunks and adding them to a list of lists is

```
      List<List<Object>> rowsOfCells = new ArrayList<List<Object>>(batchSize);
      List<Object> rowOfCells = new ArrayList<Object>(row.size());
      int start = 0;

            while (start <= row.size() / columns.size()) {
                int end = start + columns.size() - 1;
                for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {

                    rowOfCells.add(row.get(i));
                }
                rowsOfCells.add(rowOfCells);
               start = end + 1;
            }
```

**The output is:**  rowsOfCells:

```
[[http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q151345, Billygoat Hennes, http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3569037, William Windsor, http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q23003932, His Whiskers], [http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q151345, Billygoat Hennes, http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3569037, William Windsor, http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q23003932, His Whiskers], [http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q151345, Billygoat Hennes, http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3569037, William Windsor, http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q23003932, His Whiskers]]
```

**Expected output is:** rowsOfCells:

```
[[http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q151345, Billygoat Hennes], [http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3569037, William Windsor], [http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q23003932, His Whiskers]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use either [Apache Commons Collections](https://github.com/apache/commons-collections) or [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), they each have a method to partition Lists into fixed-sized sub-lists.

For example:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class SO_73194181 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> row = Arrays.asList("one", "1", "two", "2", "three", "3");
        List<List<String>> rowsOfCells;
        
        // Using Google Guava Lists class
        rowsOfCells = Lists.partition(row, 2);
        System.out.println(rowsOfCells);

        // Alternatively, using Apache Commons Collections ListUtils
        rowsOfCells = ListUtils.partition(row, 2);
        System.out.println(rowsOfCells);
    }

}
```